# jquery mouseover not staying selected

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am using this tutorial to create a flip wall: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/

In the tutorial the flip element is triggered by a .click event, i would like to change this to a .mouseover event.

i ahve setup a demo here using the .mouseover event. However when you hover over the images and move your mouse slightly the images flip back.

Heres my js:

> EDIT: Updated Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var valid = false;
$('.sponsorFlip').bind("mouseenter",function(){
    elem = $(this);
    if(!valid){ 
        // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

        elem.flip({
            direction:'lr',
            speed: 250,
            onBefore: function(){
                // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden from view with display:none)
                // into the clicked .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            }
        });

        // Setting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',true);
        valid = true;
    }
});

$('.sponsorFlip').bind("mouseleave",function(){
    elem = $(this);

    elem.revertFlip();
    valid = false;
});

});
```

Does any know how to prevent the flipping when you move the mouse slightly? I would like the element to stay flipped until the mouse leaves that element.

> Fiddle Added http://jsfiddle.net/csdQB/2/

Comment: use the http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ events instead?

Comment: @EvilEpidemic i am now using mouseenter, which works! However if i hover over all elements quickly the stay flipped?

Comment: did you also bind mouseleave to flip them back?

Comment: yes, here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/csdQB/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why you are having problems with the elements flipping again when you hover over quickly is that hoverover events are being triggered before the current event has time to finish.

I would suggest using the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) jQuery method here:

```
elem.stop().flip({
```

Unfortunately this is only half a solution because you then have the problem of the animation getting cut off early. Sorry, I'm not sure how to prevent this. Hopefully this will help you identify a more permanent solution.

You may find this article helpful: http://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try this, and found the animation was cut short! For now i am just having a mouseover event until i find a more reliable solution. Thank You!

Comment: do you found it , i need just the same